# c - send .data to a different section

Tags: gcc, linker-scripts

I want to take the symbols in the `.data` section generated for a particular C file and place them in a different section (e.g. `.mydata`) in the final executable. For example,

```
normaldata.c:  char * my_str = "this should appear in .data";
specialdata.c: char * my_special_str = "this should appear in .mydata";
```

By default, both `my_str` and `my_special_str` appear in the `.data` section. However, when I generate `specialdata.o`, I want to send anything that would have appeared in `.data` instead to `.mydata`.

I am aware that I can use the `__attribute__((section(".mydata")))` to achieve this effect, but I don't know how to apply this to a designated initializer of pointer member of a struct (I have simplified my code for this question). So instead, I'm thinking maybe I can use a linker script and send all the data from a particular file into my special section.

I tried this linker script (`link.lds`):

```
SECTIONS
{
    .mydata : { *(.data) }
}
```

with `gcc -c specialdata.c -T link.lds -o specialdata.o`, but the output of `objdump -x specialdata.o` shows a `.data` section but no `.mydata` section.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your C declaration, the `section()` attribute specifies an input section name for the linker.  The `.mydata` name, specified in the `SECTIONS` part of the linker script is the name of an *output* section.  In `.mydata` you tell the linker to place all the symbols from the "`*(.data)`" input sections into the `.mydata` output section, but your C attribute uses the name of the output section.

To get the linker to place the C variable in the correct output section, you must use the same name for the input sections in both the `.mydata` output section definition and the C `section()` attribute.

Try changing the name of the input section and using teh same name in both the linker script and the C attibutes.

Linker script:

```
SECTIONS
{
    /* Put all symbols from the .my_data input section into the
     * .mydata output section.
     */
    .mydata : { *(.my_data) }
}
```

specialdata.c source:

```
// Note that the input section name is ".my_data", not ".mydata".
char * my_special_str __attribute__((section(".my_data"))) =
    "this should appear in .mydata";
```